# Is it possible to use links in message Facebook PHP + Graph

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to add a link to the message when doing a custom publish with Graph API?

For eg:

```
<?php
$msg_body = array(
   'source' => '@'.realpath('somephoto/hey.png'),
   'message' => 'message to my wall <a href="http://likethis.com">Go here!</a>'
);
?>
```

Comment: not tried but you use link parameter 'link' => 'www.mysite.com', try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897123/graph-api-new-feed-post-object-attachment-not-showing/14029173#14029173

Answer (score 0):

No. Its not possible to embade link the way you are trying.

But try as given in documentation

[Facebook Documentation URL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/postwithgraphapi/)

```
$facebook->api('/me/feed', ...)
```

Comment: Yes, that way is possible, but how its possible to do it when publishing photos?


    $facebook->api('/page_id/photos', $args);

Answer (score 0):

Short term answer is yes, But not as you write. When you write a link in message parameter, Write it normal without tags.

```
<?php
   $msg_body = array(
  'source' => '@'.realpath('somephoto/hey.png'),
  'message' => 'message to my wall http://likethis.com"
 );
?>
```

Long term answer is, You can use link parameter instead, But that will not go with source parameter as:-

```
<?php
   $msg_body = array(
  'link' => 'http://likethis.com',
  'message' => 'message to my wall "
 );
?>
```