# How to post on user's wall in facebook after getting permission from user?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any good tutorial that teaches how to post on user's wall with API? This is the flow:

1. The user will come on my website and click on post to facebook button at the end of article.
2. He is shown sign in dialog from facebook, after sign in he will give permission to my application to post on his wall on his behalf.
3. After authorization, his shared link will be posted on his wall.
4. Upon future shares, he will not be asked for permissions since he has already given permission to post on his behalf. So in future when he clicks 'Post to Facebook' button under the article then that item will be posted to his wall without opening facebook login dialog.

I have searched a lot on tutorials but have not found any that meets my requirement.

I am very new to facebook API and have not worked with it before.

Any suggestions or link to tutorials?
Thank You!

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814158/post-to-a-facebook-users-wall-with-curl-php?rq=1

Comment: Don't want to post on page wall rather on user's profile wall

Comment: check now updated link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've code to help you to post status with an image to an user's timeline.

After user has given permission to your app , you might have received a query string parameter called 'code' , using this code , we can post to user's timeline.

$code = @$_REQUEST["code"];

```
      if(!empty($code))
      {
          // Start : Get live user access token ------------------------------------------ //
          $token_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/"
          . "access_token?"
          . "client_id=" .  FACEBOOK_APP_ID
          . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( FACEBOOK_POST_LOGIN_URL)
          . "&client_secret=" . FACEBOOK_APP_SECRECT
          . "&code=" . $code;

          $token = $this->get_app_access_token(FACEBOOK_APP_ID,FACEBOOK_APP_SECRECT,$token_url);
          $access_token = $token;

          // End : Get live user access token ------------------------------------------- //

          // Start : Create album ------------------------------------------------------ //

          $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?"
          . "access_token=". $access_token;

          $uri = 'https://graph.facebook.com/albums?access_token='.$access_token;

          $post_fields = array('name' => trim( FACEBOOK_ALBUM_NAME ));

          $curl = curl_init( $uri );
          curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
          curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE );
          curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields );

          $raw_data = curl_exec($curl);
          curl_close( $curl );

          $created_album_id = json_decode( $raw_data, $assoc = TRUE );

          // End : Create album ---------------------------------------------------------- //   

          $facebook_share_image_url = FACEBOOK_SHARE_IMAGE_PATH;

          $facebook_status_text = 'The status text';

          $graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos";

          $postData = "url=" . urlencode($facebook_share_image_url)
          . "&message=" . urlencode($facebook_status_text)
          . "&access_token=" .$access_token;

          $ch = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $graph_url);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
          $output = curl_exec($ch);
          curl_close($ch);

          // End : Add photos ------------------------------------------------------------- //
    }
```

and the function to get app access token

```
function get_app_access_token($app_id, $secret,$token_url)
{
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token';
    $token_params = array(
            "type" => "client_cred",
            "client_id" => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
            "redirect_uri" => urlencode(FACEBOOK_POST_LOGIN_URL),
            "client_secret" => FACEBOOK_APP_SECRECT
    );

    $a1 = $this->file_get_contents_curl($token_params,$token_url);
    $a2 =  str_replace("access_token=","",$a1);
    $a3 = explode("&expires",$a2);

    return $a3[0];
}
```

The other function access graph url

```
function file_get_contents_curl($params,$url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
    $headers = array(
            "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $ret = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $ret;
}
```

Hope it helps..!!

Comment: You're welcome , let me know if you've query regarding the same

Comment: Your code is very helpful. I am just near to solution. I am getting this error when I run the application after getting access token: Global id xxxx is not allowed. Please use application specific ID

Comment: What is specific application ID. The APP ID I created for my application? or profile id of the user?

Comment: The APP ID for your created app

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple facebook sharer URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=YOURPAGEURL
```

Where YOURPAGEURL is the page URL which you want to share.. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not what I want. I want when user clicks on "Post to facebook" button then that link will be posted on user's wall without opening any dialog box from facebook. Obviously the dialog will open when the user has not given the permission, but once user has given the permission I want to save his tokens in db and next time check those tokens against user id and post to his profile without opening facebook dialog.

Answer (score 0):

you have to permission pubish_stream on your app and then try this using curl:-
Also you need a user access token then send access token with curl call

```
$attachment =  array(
        'access_token' => $access_token,
        'message' => 'i m success to using graph api for post wall',
        'name' => 'Wall Post using graph api',
        'link' => 'www.mysite.com',
        'description' => 'Using the Graph API, any Facebook users Wall feed may be accessed by using this URL:',
        'picture'=>'http://example.com/images/noimage.png'
 );
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$facebook_id/feed";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  //to suppress the curl output
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
print_r($result)
```

For more :- [Graph API new feed post object-Attachment not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897123/graph-api-new-feed-post-object-attachment-not-showing/14029173#14029173)

[Post to a Facebook user's wall with cURL PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814158/post-to-a-facebook-users-wall-with-curl-php?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you very much. Have to try this. 
Will surely accept the answer if it solves my problem.

Comment: your welcome dude let me know if you have any issue and also show your code what you have done